# Performance testing in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm currently doing some improvement to Apache cassandra 1.2.8, and I want to do some performance testing on the data base. What is the best way of doing performance testing on this kind of NO-SQL data base? are there any tools or standards which we can use for performance testings?

Comment: When you do some improvements on a RDBMS, how do you do performance test?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB). While not a standard it has been used by quite a few products including Cassandra.